# I want to combine two scripts into one

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm switching CSS using jQuery toggleClass.

```
$ (".test").click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

If I click other than the menu in Bootstrap, the menu will be hidden. I also want to **toggleClass ('active')** when clicked outside the menu.

```
$(document).click(function (event) {
   if (!$(event.target).is('.navbar-collapse *')) {
    $('.navbar-collapse').collapse('hide');
  }
});
```

Can it be one script? Or can I activate two functions after **if**?　Please help me, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that `.test` might be the class of multiple items. Your

```
$ (".test").click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

toggles this `class` for the specific element, while if `toggle` is what you want, then you can do something like this:

```js
$(".wrapper, .test, .outside-menu").click(function(e) {
    if ($(this).hasClass("test")) $(this).toggleClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
    else if ($(this).hasClass("outside-menu")) e.stopPropagation();
    else { //This is the wrapper's case
        //YOUR CODE HERE
        $(".test").removeClass("active");
    }
});
```

```css
.active {
    color: green;
}

.outside-menu {
    background-color: gray;
}

html, body, .wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
    BEFORE MENU
    <div class="outside-menu">
        MENU
        <div class="test">TEEEEST1</div>
        <div class="test">TEEEEST2</div>
        <div class="test">TEEEEST3</div>
    </div>
    AFTER MENU
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your replay. This time, I study

Comment: Thank you for your replay. This time, I study wrapper. However, I don't know where to replace ** (! $ (Event.target) .is ('.navbar-collapse *')) {
     $ ('.navbar-collapse'). Collapse ('hide') **. I have been studying for a month. That's why Bootstrap uses Grayscale templete. However, I don't like the menu not closing unless I click the toggle button or the menu link. Of course, I also learned that there are various off-screen menus. However, I'm trying to find out if I can do it with the toggle button of Navbar. I'm sorry for my broken English.

Comment: @yuki I have edited my answer. You can see that in the snippet there is an `if`, an `else if` and an `else`. These are 3 different cases. The third case is the `else`, which is not the test, nor the outside-menu, therefore it is the wrapper. I have added a comment for `YOUR CODE HERE` at the place where you can put your other code.

Comment: @yuki please let me know if there are further unclarities. Also, if this answer solves the problem for you, then you might consider accepting it as the correct answer.

Comment: https://startbootstrap.com/previews/grayscale   I want to change this free template  at smartphone size, and when the menu opens with the toggle button, the icon changes and I want to click outside the menu to close it. But I can't do them at the same time yet...

Comment: @yuki thank you for your comment! Since you did not confirm that my fiddle solved your problem, I presume that it is not a solution yet, please correct me if I'm wrong. If I am right in assuming that my code is not solving your problem yet, then please explain how is it failing to meet your expectations? Can you describe a step-by-step process of testing it and outline the difference between your expectations and the actual behavior of my code? That would likely clarify your current problem to me and allow me to help you further.